# pROC versus ROCR

Tags: r, roc

This is a very basic question but I don't get why the following provides different results when applying pROC or ROCR, see plot.

```
Exp = c(1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1)
Pred = c(63.2,110.8,55.57,34.40,34.16,53.8,76.3,76.3,94.8,61.3)

# ########################## pROC ##########################
rocobj <- roc(response = Exp, predictor = Pred)
plot.roc(rocobj,main="pROC")

# ########################## ROCR ##########################
ROCRpred<-prediction(Pred,Exp)
plot(performance(ROCRpred,'tpr','fpr'),main="ROCR")
```

The interpretation of 1/0 should be same, why is it not?

Another question is what if I want to use say P/N for levels? Is there an order in which I have to define them?
[image]

Comment: The order of your factors matter and each package probably deals with them a little differently, if you get nonsense results just reverse the order for a "correct" plot.

Comment: Does a higher value for 'Pred' mean a higher probability for an 'Exp' with a 1 or a higher probability for an 'Exp' with a 0?

Comment: @Martijn it is the former, the higher 'Pred' the higher the probability for 'Exp'

Comment: @maciekj so the 110.8 prediction should correspond to a high probability for Exp=1 ?

Answer (score 5):

#### The `prediction` function

If you do not specify which class is a positive case and a negative case then the prediction function needs to make up it's mind about positive and negative cases automatically. It does this as following:

```
> prediction

...

if (label.format == "ordered") {
    if (!is.null(label.ordering)) {
        stop(paste("'labels' is already ordered. No additional", 
            "'label.ordering' must be supplied."))
    }
    else {
        levels <- levels(labels[[1]])
    }
}
else {
    if (is.null(label.ordering)) {
        if (label.format == "factor") 
            levels <- sort(levels(labels[[1]]))
        else levels <- sort(unique(unlist(labels)))
    }
    else {
        if (!setequal(unique(unlist(labels)), label.ordering)) {
            stop("Label ordering does not match class labels.")
        }
        levels <- label.ordering
    }
    for (i in 1:length(labels)) {
        if (is.factor(labels)) 
            labels[[i]] <- ordered(as.character(labels[[i]]), 
              levels = levels)
        else labels[[i]] <- ordered(labels[[i]], levels = levels)
    }
}

....
```

by specifying `label.ordering = c(1,0)` like

```
ROCRpred<-prediction(Pred, Exp, label.ordering = c(1,0))
```

you will get what you want.

**Note that you can find help in R by typing `help(prediction)` and when you type just the name of the function `prediction` then you can see the function itself. (and of course you can replace this for any other function)**

---

#### Conventions

You better use the following "conventions":

1. Use the 'higher' label for the positive class and the 'lower' label for the negative class.
2. Use the higher score a stronger tendency to the positive class. (currently you give the highest prediction score for the lowest class labels)

The following is a quote from the help file of the `prediction` function:

> Since scoring classifiers give relative tendencies towards a negative
>   (low scores) or positive (high scores) class, it has to be declared
>   which class label denotes the negative, and which the positive class.
>   Ideally, labels should be supplied as ordered factor(s), the lower
>   level corresponding to the negative class, the upper level to the
>   positive class. If the labels are factors (unordered), numeric,
>   logical or characters, ordering of the labels is inferred from R's
>   built-in < relation (e.g. 0 < 1, -1 < 1, 'a' < 'b', FALSE < TRUE). Use
>   label.ordering to override this default ordering. Please note that the
>   ordering can be locale-dependent e.g. for character labels '-1' and
>   '1'.

So if you use

```
ROCRpred<-prediction(-Pred, Exp)
```

it works as well (in the sense that the curve is in the upper half, but note that there can still be a difference: `prediction(-Pred, Exp)` is not the same as `prediction(Pred, -Exp)`, an image is shown later in this post).

---

#### Why did `roc` work but `prediction` not?

The `roc` function from the `pROC` package automatically determines the direction whether a higher score relates to a higher/lower probability of the positive class.

You still have to be very clear about the positive cases and negative cases though. You can get different results:

[image: difference positives/negatives]

Comment: Martijn, thank you very much, an outstanding analysis! 
Regarding the P/N assignmtent, we are dealing here with a poorly performing experimental setup, unable to detect so called strong binders (P) from the week ones. This can best be seen in the 110.8 case, where the exp assey misses it.

Comment: @maciekj could you write a more complete story. Something about binders and detecting poor ones (or is it detecting strong ones?). I am not sure what your Exp (how do you assign these numbers 0 and 1 to the cases) and Pred mean (what does 110.8 mean and how is it measured) and what your aim is with plotting an ROC curve. P/N refers to positive negative?

Comment: The assays measures binding between a molecule ‘agent’ and  a ‘cell’.
For a given genotype (alleles with binding affinities) we get two values

1. EXPERIMENTAL results, ‘Exp’: P for ‘positive’ result meaning agent binds the cell or N for the ‘negative’ result.

2. IN SILICO prediction (ODE model for tumour size), ‘Pred’: simulated tumour size.

Both the experimental setup and model are imperfect. The assays clearly misses the strong binding subjects/phenotypes. 
The model doesn’t fully use the information about the binding strength due to gaps in bioinformatics.

Comment: Marijn, in the above I used 1 for 'P' and 0 for 'N'

Comment: Martijn, hope my explanation was clear. When you write 'You still have to be very clear about the positive cases and negative cases though. You can get different results' it's not up to me to assign the 1/0 lebels, they are given by experiment. The 'Pred' is more my job, is the model good or rubish. Right now it looks like it's the latter :(
The most important question is how do I set up pROC and ROCR so they provide cosistent results.

Comment: @maciekj So, you model tumour size and this can be a number like say 63.2 or 110.8. Is a larger tumor size associated with a higher or a lower probability that the agent binds the cell (exp = P/1)?

Comment: Apologies, I've used a misleading end point, it should rather be formulated as: 'Pred' is the number of activated cells. Meaning that the higher number of activated cells corresponds to higher probability for the binding between agnet and the cells.

Comment: So, you model the number of activated cells, which is a number like 63.2 or 110.8. Is a larger number of modeled activated cells associated with a higher or lower probability that the agent binds the cell (Exp = P/1)? Say you have a modeled value Pred=110.8 should you expect Exp=1 or Exp=0?

Comment: Yes there is this association, i.e. I expect Exp=1 for Pred=110.8

Comment: So for your three exp=0 you get your highest pred values 76.3, 94.8, 110.8 and for your seven  exp=1 you get your smallest values 34.40, 34.16, 55.57, 61.3, 63.2, 53.8, 76.3, which is nearly the most possible opposite result that you can get. What do you wish to learn from the ROC curve?

Comment: I have number of parameters I can vary in my ODE model, one goal is to optimize those parameters yielding the largest AUC of the ROC, anopther is to identify those which influence the AUC most. Also, sort of 'dose-response' curves, i.e. 'parameter-AUC' curves, could be plotted

Answer (score 1):

The devil is in details and that is something that I also overlooked in the past.

The issue is that pROC (without notifying the user) will flip the curve if the AUC is much lower than 0.5. This is controlled by an argument named `direction` which by default is `direction = "auto"` I put the description at the end of my answer, but as a short answer, if your cases have higher values than controls (e.g cases are marked with `1` and controls with `0`), then you should use `direction = "<"` and if it is the opposite, you should use `direction = ">"`.

This is what the manual of `pROC::roc` says:

> ```
> direction: in which direction to make the comparison?  “auto”
>           (default): automatically define in which group the median is
>           higher and take the direction accordingly.  “>”: if the
>           predictor values for the control group are higher than the
>           values of the case group (controls > t >= cases).  “<”: if
>           the predictor values for the control group are lower or equal
>           than the values of the case group (controls < t <= cases).
>           You should set this explicity to “>” or “<” whenever you are
>           resampling or randomizing the data, otherwise the curves will
>           be biased towards higher AUC values.
> ```